# autoinstall and zfs on root partition

Tags: partitioning, raid, zfs

We're moving our custom ubuntu installers from the d-i to [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference) and I'm wondering whether it's possible to install zfs on the root partition automatically. Ideally I'd like to setup a raid-0 between two disks in my system formatted with ZFS.

I see no mention of this in the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used zfs with autoinstall, but the `storage` section of the `autoinstall` file essentially gets passed through to *curtin*.  The *curtin* documentation suggests zfs support is there, but experimental

https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html?highlight=zfs#format-command

> Filesystems support for ZFS on root is Experimental. Utilizing the the
> fstype: zfsroot will indicate to curtin that it should automatically
> inject the appropriate type: zpool and type: zfs command structures
> based on which target volume is specified in the format command. There
> may be only one zfsroot entry. The disk that contains the zfsroot must
> be partitioned with a GPT partition table. Curtin will fail to install
> if these requirements are not met.